# Need assistance fine turning capturing response XSLT

Tags: xslt

Below is the results of a request and I'm trying to capture the EFTCardNum MaskVal

```
         <EFTCardNum MaskVal="123456******1234">1234560000123456</EFTCardNum>
```

For response I'm currently using.

```
  <xsl:value-of select="s:Envelope/s:Body/a:EFTCardInqResponse[a:EFTCardNum/@MaskVal]/a:EFTCardNum"/>
```

And I'm only bringing back "1234560000123456" and need to bring back the masked section "123456******1234".  Hope this is enough information.

Comment: Wouldn't you just need to add `@MaskVal` to the end of your select statement to select the `MaskVal` attribute? So: `<xsl:value-of select="s:Envelope/s:Body/a:EFTCardInqResponse[a:EFTCardNum/@MaskVal]/a:EFTCardNum/@MaskVal"/>`?

Comment: I just tested and that worked perfectly.  Slowly getting the hang of xslt.

Comment: Just realized I can simply use:    <xsl:value-of select="s:Envelope/s:Body/a:EFTCardInqResponse/a:EFTCardNum/@MaskVal"/>